# How can I disable editting for GtkTextView in C?

Tags: c, gtk, scrollbar, gtktextview

I tried this one and it generates a TextView window:

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/gtktextview/

But I don't want it to be editable.

BTW, how can I show the scroll bar when the text overflows?

Answer (score 1):

Check http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTextView.html:

There's a `gtk_text_view_set_editable` function.

You can add scrollbars to widgets by adding them to a `GtkScrolledWindow`. Eg:

```
GtkWidget* scrolled = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (scrolled), view);
```

And then instead of calling pack_start with view, call it with scrolled.

For centering, a `GtkScrolledWindow` isn't a top-level window so its position depends on the parent container (a `VBox` in the example). There are parameters of `pack_start` for padding etc which might get what you want.

Comment: I used `gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);` for a normal window,but seems it's not working for scrolled window?