# Memory implications of passing literals/objects/classes to functions with thousands of calls

Tags: javascript, memory

## Background

A framework I'm writing involves a `Figure` class calling a function `SetTranslate( x, y )` on a `Renderer` class. In turn, the `Renderer` class has to store the arguments `(x, y)` passed to `SetTranslate`.

**There can be thousands of figures, and thus a single user action may trigger thousands of such calls.**

I'm a bit concerned about the memory implications (and garbage collection ones) of using objects or classes compared to literals for such calls.

The specifics are below.

## Same for all options

<sub>Do forgive me for using class-like syntax in the code below, but it makes no difference to the actual question. One can easily substitute the `Class` syntax with standard JS functions & prototype syntax.</sub>

In all the options below, the figure class is constructed with a property `rect` that is a new instance of a class `Rect`:

```
Figure = new Class({

    // Constructor 
    initialize: function() {
        this.rect = new Rect( 0, 0, 10, 10 );
    }    
});
```

## Option 1 - using primitive value parameters

The Figure class:

```
Figure = new Class({
    render: function( aRenderer ) {
        aRenderer.setTranslate( this.rect.x, this.rect.y );
    }       
});
```

The Renderer class:

```
Renderer = new Class({

    // Constructor 
    initialize: function() {
        this.translation = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        };
    },

    setTranslate: function( x, y ) {
        this.translation.x = x;
        this.translation.y = y;
    }       
});
```

### Concerns

If I'm not mistaken, there's no memory allocation involved here, so no real concerns - it's straightforward.

## Option 2 - using object literals

The Figure class:

```
Figure = new Class({    
    render: function( aRenderer ) {
        aRenderer.setTranslate( { x: this.rect.x, y: this.rect.y } );
    }       
});
```

The Renderer class:

```
Renderer = new Class({

    // Constructor 
    initialize: function() {
        this.translation = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        };
    },

    setTranslate: function( aTranslation ) {
        this.translation = aTranslation;
    }       
});
```

### Concerns

My question is if by using

```
        aRenderer.setTranslate( { x: this.rect.x, y: this.rect.y } );
```

a new object is created. Also, by executing

```
        this.translation = aTranslation;
```

wouldn't the previous object now go to garbage collection?

## Option 3 - using class instances

The Figure class:

```
Figure = new Class({    
    render: function( aRenderer ) {
        // rect.getTopLeft() returns new Point( x, y );
        aRenderer.setTranslate( this.rect.getTopLeft() );
    }       
});
```

The Renderer class:

```
Renderer = new Class({

    // Constructor 
    initialize: function() {
        this.translation = new Point( 0, 0 );
    },

    setTranslate: function( aTranslation ) {
        this.translation = aTranslation;
    }       
});
```

### Concerns

The fact that `getTopLeft()` returns a `new Point( x, y )` makes it explicit that memory allocation will be part of this:

```
        // rect.getTopLeft() returns new Point( x, y );
        aRenderer.setTranslate( this.rect.getTopLeft() );
```

And it's pretty clear that with this line:

```
        this.translation = aTranslation;
```

the previous `translation` object (class) will go into garbage collection.

Is this any different from option 2?

And since this is the ideal solution for me (the Point class has methods that could be useful for other things within `setTranslate`) would it be a problem given that there may be thousands of such calls per user action (compared to option 1 and 2, that is)?

Comment: option1's setTranslate() would likely use the least ram because  it doesn't create a new object.

Comment: If you're really crazy about memory consumption, you could simply pass the reference to `this.rect` which is already an object with `x` and `y` properties :-) This would be a dirty design however, and might work not well for non-rectangles.

Comment: @Bergi `this.rect` is really `this.bounds`, which all figures have (even `Circle` and `Line` - descendants of `Figure`). The is a real issue here, `Figure` has a method `getBounds`; For some figures, this simply returns `this.bounds`, but for others (like a line, which is defined by `fromPoint` and 'toPoint` - this is calculated on the fly. So I can just have all figures have `this.bounds`; update it for figures that calculate it on the fly, and return it.

Comment: But the main thing that bothers me - should I even care? So there are 5000 objects in GC. Performance/memory wise, what's the penalty? I'm asking this because while memory gets bigger and processors faster, code is the only thing that remains static. So I believe one should always prioritised code quality over memory and performance. So how bad 5000 GC objects are? I guess it's a separate question.

Comment: Yes, you should always go for clean code first. Iff you have performance problems, then you'd go investigate what the main issue is and fix it. Whether 5000 objects is much or not depends a lot on the environment, and the timeframe over which that was measured.

Comment: if you're not rendering graphics in real-time, like a game, then tiny GC pauses don't really matter to your users. if you do have to keep something running constantly, and want no flicker, then it behooves you to keep object creation at a minimum.

Comment: I've posted some benchmarks [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738897). Doesn't look too serious to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that object pools are a very effective way of controlling the memory behaviour of something like this. Allocate up front the number of objects that you need concurrently and then reuse them to avoid garbage collection issues.

To answer your question,

```
aRenderer.setTranslate( { x: this.rect.x, y: this.rect.y } );
```

will create a new object and yes, in your example the previous translate object would be eligible for GC (assuming there are no other references to it).

Comment: I don't think an object pool for the `Points` would be any better than his option 1 - there is only one translation per renderer anyway.