# Benckmarks for Browser Garbage Collection

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, garbage-collection

It seems that many are conscious of Garbage Collection of Javascript instances.

I'm writing a framework, and for code quality purposes could really benefit from functions that return new instances that will then be garbage collected. In my case, as single user action could create around 5000 such instances.

Object pools are possible, but will complicate the code.

Are there some benchmarks that demonstrate the penalty of garbage collection - both in terms of memory and performance?

Comment: Your question is interesting, but I'm afraid it's too subjective for SO. In general I'd say that you shouldn't worry about it, unless you’ve identified a performance problem. In other words: don’t over-focus on speed metrics; look at the big picture.

Comment: Agreed. I'll edit it.

Comment: these days, only games that need to run smoothly on crappy phones need to worry about GC pauses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With relation to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27369360/1179377), I've run a little test, which 13 times creates **10,000 instances** that shall be garbage collected.

## Key insights

- GC takes very little time - between 1/10-2.4 *milliseconds*.
- On average there are about 2 GC occurrences per a block of 10,000 instances.
- Memory is kept below the 20MB mark.

## Test results

`Test01` was triggered a few times using a button. The console timeline shows this:

[image: Google Console view]

## The code

```
// Bounds

function Bounds() {
    this.x = Math.random();
    this.y = Math.random();
    this.h = Math.random();
    this.w = Math.random();
}

// Rect

function Rect() {
}

Rect.prototype.getBounds = function() {
    return new Bounds();
}

// Renderer

function Renderer() {
    this.bounds = null;
}

Renderer.prototype.setBounds = function( aBounds ) {
    this.bounds = aBounds;
}

// Test

function Test01() {
    var iRenderer = new Renderer();
    var iRect = new Rect();

    for ( var i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {
        iRenderer.setBounds( iRect.getBounds() );
    }
}
```

## Specs

- 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5.
- 4GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Chrome 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit)